# Memory profiling of large-scale time-sensitive software

Tags: c++, memory-management, profiling

I have a program that is very large scale (tens of thousands of lines of code). It also must perform calculations and produce output in a time sensitive manner (although it is not strictly real-time). I would like to profile the memory usage, to ensure that we're not overstepping array bounds, producing memory leaks, et cetera. I'm working on a Linux platform with C++. In the past I've used Valgrind, but I am not able to use it for this program because of the time sensitivity constraints. How can I go about validating my program to ensure there are no memory errors?

Comment: Maybe you should consider doing unit tests instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [efence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence) in the past and works a treat. Downside is that it has a fairly large overhead (typically allocates a page before and after each allocation to detect overruns)

Comment: It looks like this can only be used for C. But I really like the concept. Is there an equivalent for C++?